# Client connection's MAC and IP address in Oracle

Tags: oracle, network-protocols

Under MS SQL Server you can use the **master.sys.sysprocesses** and the **master.sys.dm_exec_connections** system views to retrieve the MAC address and the IP address of a given TCP/IP client connection.

Is there any way to do exactly this in Oracle Database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can see IP addresses, but not MAC, when using the SQL views - in addition, the client may be behind any number of pieces of network hardware, so it's unlikely that the server knows their MAC address anyway. How were you using this information?

Comment: @Damien Now you made me curious - how do you get the IP address from the SQL views?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt - Sorry, I left the word "Server" out - I can see the IP addresses in the **SQL Server** views mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to obtain the IP from sys_context:

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the client's machine name by querying v$session, and you could try using utl_inaddr.get_host_address() to obtain the IP adress for the host name, but

- you'll have to do additional processing of the machine name from v$session, since it isn't always a valid host name
- you won't get the MAC address without querying the OS directly

In fact, I'm surprised SQL server provides this information - I guess it's doing an ARP lookup in the background for obtaining the MAC adress for a given IP adress. You could mimic this in your application code, of course.

Why do you need this information?